# Can Google Cloud Messaging work with Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, google-cloud-messaging

I'm wondering, is it possible to make Facebook application send message via GCM service to my android app updates about new posts/messages/contacts etc? I'm almost sure that something like that is possible for Google+, and also I noticed that Facebooks API messages structure is very similar (or identical) to GCM messages. That is why i think it should be possible.

In other words: Is it possible to make Facebook application work as a server that stores devices IDs and sends messages on some changes via Google Cloud Messaging?

Comment: Oh. I would love to know if this works. +1 for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to drop in some kind of middleware to handle the interaction between the Facebook and Google API's -- with that being said, it's definitely possible.

Facebook's API offers the ability to subscribe to events (realtime). There's only a handful of events that you can subscribe to, and everything is outlined [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/01/31/how-to--subscribing-to-data-changes-using-the-real-time-updates-api/) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/).

Alternatively, you could long poll for data that's not revealed via their realtime API. Just think about API limites, etc. before hand.

Keep in mind that you'll need to create a Facebook application, and your users will have to authenticate the Facebook application so that you have information to whatever info you're trying to access. Sames goes for Google.

Comment: Your idea looks pretty interesting, I have suspended this project for a while, but when I'm gonna get back to it I will try it for sure. I have accepted your answer since I haven't found any other solution, nor any clues. Thanks for help!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to reach out should you have any questions about the Facebook Graph API.